# Como lidar com frameworks e tecnologias prontas?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, framework

Estou com uma dúvida faz um tempo e acho que pode até ser uma dúvida comum. Não sei muito bem como colocar a pergunta, mas vou tentar. Quando comecei a programar eu lidei com linguagens como PHP, C, C++. O que usei mais na prática mesmo foi o PHP. Basicamente eu tinha que desenvolver *tudo*, os códigos para autenticação/autorização e segurança, os códigos para interação com MySQL, etc.

Depois de 3 anos trabalhando com PHP aprendi o C# e comecei a trabalhar com o framework .NET desde então. Gosto muito das funcionalidades do framework e da linguagem também, que é "mais" orientada a objetos que o PHP, além de ser fortemente tipada e etc.

O problema é que esse tempo todo eu tenho uma dúvida bastante grande. Como existe todo um framework disponível, muitas coisas já estão prontas. Então, se eu preciso de bancos de dados, já tenho o EF ou o NHibernate, se eu preciso utilizar serviços REST já tenho o WebAPI, se eu preciso de autenticação/autorização em aplicações web já tenho o ASP.NET Identity.

E quando vou ler sobre como usar essas tecnologias todas basicamente encontro tutoriais e artigos dizendo: "faça assim" e então é sempre daquele jeito que as coisas funcionam e pronto. Isso tudo deixa uma dúvida do tipo: "tendo *tanta* coisa pronta e tudo já explicado exatamente *como* usar, o que eu tenho que programar de verdade?"

E essa pergunta é muito estranha, porque afinal, se eu estou trabalhando no projeto eu deveria saber o que preciso programar. Só que com tanta coisa disponível eu costumo me perder e quando vejo estou simplesmente replicando códigos que li sobre como aplicar determinadas tecnologias.

Sei que existe o modelo de domínio a ser desenvolvido. Mas isso é tudo? Quando lidamos com frameworks como o .NET só desenvolvemos o modelo de domínio e o integramos à tecnologia do jeito que é eplicado em tutoriais e etc? Como se lida com esse tipo de situação?

Comment: Só uma ressalva C# é `Orientado a Objeto` (o `mais` ficou estranho)

Comment: O fato de ser difícil perguntar pode indicar que é difícil responder. Pelo menos deve ser difícil responder sem dar opinião.

Comment: @FCCDias, é eu percebi que esse mais ia ficar estranho. Mas o que eu quis dizer, é que o PHP tem elementos de orientação a objeto, mas não é totalmente orientado a objetos como o C#.

Comment: @user1620696, concordo com essa última afirmação, porque, eu programo em C# e PHP, e tenho a mesma visão!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sempre me questionei a mesma coisa ao longo da vida (já passei por Clipper, VB, Assembly, C, C++, Java, C#, HTML e JavaScript).

Antigamente eu desenvolvia tudo na mão, por diversas razões, principalmente:

- Não existia Internet
- Tudo que eu fazia, fazia por curiosidade e gosto
- Queria aprender tudo, e como não estava em uma empresa, tempo não era problema

Depois que entrei para o mundo corporativo, pude perceber que já não estava mais no mesmo cenário de antes.

Quando um sistema era vendido, ele **tinha** que ser entregue no prazo. Se um componente novo era necessário para esse sistema, a decisão de comprar ou não um pronto (em vez de fazer um em casa "a partir do zero") baseava-se basicamente em tempo e custo. O fator "somos capazes de fazer, basta nos dar um pouco de tempo" não pesava tanto.

Como tudo na vida, essa decisão tem dois lados. Comprar/baixar um componente/framework e sair usando seguindo algum tutorial/manual é muito prático, e agiliza muito o processo de desenvolvimento. Contudo, não conhecer o que está por debaixo do capô às vezes é muito perigoso.

Por exemplo, se o componente apresentar um mal funcionamento, apesar de todas as instruções terem sido seguidas à risca, o que fazer? Nem sempre se tem acesso ao código fonte, e pode ser que ninguém tenha contato rápido com a equipe de desenvolvimento, e pode ser que nunca venha a ter.

Claro que esse é um risco ponderado na hora de tomar a decisão, mas existe mais um detalhe que, ao longo dos anos, vi consumir horas e horas de desenvolvimento à procura de soluções para problemas provenientes da falta de conhecimento sobre o funcionamento de um componente pronto.

Um caso não tão recente, decidiram utilizar um componente grid em C#/ASP.Net para exibir e paginar registros provenientes de um banco de dados. Assim que o grid foi implantado, o acesso à página ficou extremamente lento. Depois de algum trabalho e pesquisa, descobriu-se que o grid na verdade carregava todos os registros, e os armazenava no `ViewState` da página para não precisar mais acessar o banco, e poder paginar tudo corretamente.

Isso não é errado dependendo do caso, mas naquele cenário em específico, a consulta retornava milhares de registros, carregando a página em excesso!

Ou seja, nunca seria possível resolver o problema daquele componente, sem ter o conhecimento da tecnologia sobre a qual ele foi montado.

Não acredito existir uma resposta final para essa questão. Depende muito do caso, e de qual objetivo se pretende atingir.

Hoje, anos depois de ter começado a programar, vejo o quão saudável foram todas as horas atrás do computador "reinventando a roda". Confesso ao longo desses anos, minha "produção final" foi bem pequena, se comparado com a quantidade de horas que trabalhei, mas nesse caso o ganho não foi um produto pronto, e sim o conhecimento em si.

Me tornei professor, e procuro deixar isso bem claro durante as aulas, visto que quase todos meus alunos já atuam no mercado: fazer as coisas a partir do zero é ótimo se você quiser aprender uma tecnologia, ou quiser exercitar sua lógica, do mesmo jeito que eu fiz por anos (e ainda faço). Contudo, há momentos onde o tempo é crucial, e é nesses momentos que utilizamos frameworks e componentes prontos.

Mas, mesmo quando utilizando um componente/framework pronto, sempre é bom saber que não existe mágica, tudo que ele faz, podemos fazer (com algumas exceções), e por isso não devemos ter nenhum tipo de *devoção cega* para com o componente, sendo necessário saber ao menos um mínimo sobre a tecnologia sobre a qual o componente trabalha.

Comment: Procurei ser meio neutro, apesar de parte da resposta expressar um pouco da minha opinião.

Comment: eu li sua resposta acredito ser experiência e não opinião, parabéns pela sua resposta... eu gostei muito

Comment: Valeu, @FCCDias! Também compartilho da opinião da sua resposta!

Answer (score 3):

#### A grande importância de saber o que está fazendo ?

Percebo que existem o que sabem, e os que usam framework. Como relatado no framework já vem pronto é para usar daquele jeito, é uma forma de economizar tempo, padronizar software, etc.

O mercado exige software feitos em menor tempo, categorizados e que se alguém da equipe saia tenha outro que vai substituir o mesmo com conhecimento bem parecido.

PHP, Java, .Net Framework (C#, VB.Net) e etc., todos esses possuem hoje no mercado ótimos framework que nos ajude a melhorar a nossa codificação e solucionar problemas que levaria um certo tempo. Claro que a implementação deles você como um desenvolvedor e conhecedor consegue replicar ou melhorar. *Exemplo*: eu criei no meus Sistemas Web MVC ASP.NET, o meu controle de usuários personalizados fazendo `Heranças`/`Implementação` nas classes base da mesma e colocando internamente a minha lógica, e muitos amigos da arquitetura .NET fazem isso.

#### O Ponto Chave é você sabe programar em determinado linguagem e/ou arquitetura de desenvolvimento?

Conheço pessoas que sabem Laravel (que é um excelente framework para PHP), e estão tão acostumados com o mesmo que quando ele te passo um erro você não consegue resolver pela falta de conhecimento da linguagem PHP, esse ponto da questão é que limita muitos desenvolvedores a saber um framework e não saber a linguagem.

#### O que é Importante?

Importante é aprender a linguagem e todas suas ramificações, para depois utilizar um framework para agilizar seu desenvolvimento, sendo que não fique preso as tecnologias auxiliares e sim que possam resolver todos os problemas com o conhecimento da linguagem.

Eu tenho uma frase: **E nunca saberei tudo, mas, eu sempre estudarei para saber tudo**, dificilmente você sabe tudo, mas, eu vivo estudando para absorver mais e mais, C# por exemplo está sempre em evolução para quem começou 1.0 e hoje tem 4.5.1 imagine o quanto já estudei e o quanto me deparo com novidades.